# How to parse json with more then one array?

Tags: javascript, json

My json looks like this:

```
{
   "0":[
      [

      ]
   ],
   "103,57,337,79":[
      [
         "czas"
      ]
   ],
   "195,193,418,37":{
      "1":[
         "NOWY",
         "DRYBLING",
         "3600"
      ]
   },
   "201,239,796,44":{
      "2":[
         "Nowy",
         "system",
         "dryblingu",
         "zapewnia",
         "cyzyjną",
         "i",
         "płynną"
      ]
   },
   "208,290,495,41":{
      "3":[
         "kontrolę",
         "nad",
         "ruchami",
         "zawodnika."
      ]
   },
   "221,367,301,36":{
      "4":[
         "PEŁNY",
         "REALIZM"
      ]
   },
   "234,411,861,44":{
      "5":[
         "Nowe,",
         "realistyczne",
         "style",
         "gry",
         "sprawiają,",
         "że",
         "gra",
         "przypomina"
      ]
   },
   "234,456,798,47":{
      "6":[
         "prawdziwą",
         "piłkę",
         "bardziej,",
         "niż",
         "kiedykolwiek",
         "wcześniej."
      ]
   },
   "186,528,562,46":{
      "7":[
         ">",
         "REPREZENTUJ",
         "swóJ",
         "KRAJ"
      ]
   },
   "246,583,788,42":{
      "8":[
         "Walcz",
         "o",
         "miejsce",
         "w",
         "kadrze",
         "narodowej",
         "na",
         "Mistrzostwa"
      ]
   },
   "248,626,835,42":{
      "9":[
         "Świata",
         "FIFA",
         "TM",
         "2010",
         "w",
         "trybie",
         "Zostań",
         "Gwiazdą:",
         "Klub",
         "i",
         "Kraj."
      ]
   },
   "249,703,623,42":{
      "10":[
         "POZNAJ",
         "SWOJEGO",
         "PRZECIWNIKA"
      ]
   },
   "250,752,821,46":{
      "11":[
         "Raporty",
         "prezentowane",
         "przed",
         "meczami",
         "zawierają",
         "cenne"
      ]
   },
   "244,799,694,44":{
      "12":[
         "informacje",
         "dotyczące",
         "następnego",
         "przeciwnika."
      ]
   },
   "244,872,361,46":{
      "13":[
         "ZOSTAŃ",
         "MISTRZEM"
      ]
   },
   "240,925,686,45":{
      "14":[
         "Rozegraj",
         "swoim",
         "ulubionym",
         "klubem",
         "cały",
         "sezon"
      ]
   },
   "233,977,229,40":{
      "15":[
         "w",
         "trybie",
         "Sezon."
      ]
   }
}
```

i need all rows but how?

````
        var objee = JSON.parse(stringJson);
        for(var key in objee){
   rowContent = key + " " + objee[key] + "<br>";

   divText.innerHTML += rowContent;
} ```



But i need only values from tables how can i do it?
````

Comment: What do you mean by `all rows`. Perhaps add an example of what the end result should look like?
Also, make sure your json is ok (first two elements are arrays of arrays while the rest are objects with arrays)

Comment: Please add the expected output to create a [mcve]